# Excel new column macro

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have the following data imported from a .csv. So when I open this CSV (using a macro). The following lines will be printed.

```
Group Name  Name              UserName  Enabled   Lastchanged
Grp-Doe     John doe          j.doe     True      9-10-2017 07:25
Grp-Doe     Janna x           j.x       False     10-10-2017 08:10
```

Now, I want new column called `NameChanged` that uses an excel formula. Basically I wan't the following output.

```
Group Name  Name              UserName  Enabled   Lastchanged      NameChanged
Grp-Doe     John doe          j.doe     True      9-10-2017 07:25  John doe disabled on:09-10-2017
Grp-Doe     Janna x           j.x       False     1-10-2017 08:10  Janna X
```

The column `NameChanged` is calculated by a formula I wrote and I still posess.

Is there a macro function that automatically add's this data?

I tried this so far:

```
Sub AddData() 
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value = "=ALS(D2="False"; B2&" 
"&"Disabled op: "&TEKST(E2;"d-m-jjjj uu:mm"); B2)" 
End Sub
```

This gave me a syntax error

Comment: What did you try so far? You will need to at least start on your own, because this is not a free code writing service. Please [edit] your original question and add the code you already have so far. Tell use where you got stuck or in which line you got errors (and which).

Comment: You will need to set the as .Formula not .Value. Also, i suspect the following "=ALS(D2="False"; B2&" 
"&"Disabled op: "&TEKST(E2;"d-m-jjjj uu:mm"); B2)"  needs some checking to ensure reconciles to a string though that may be as i am  using different regional settings.

Comment: When I use .Formula instead of .Value the editor stops at the second " mark. How could I avoid this?

Comment: You need double all " inside " "

Comment: You need to escape the inner "". What does the actual formula in the cell look like?  =ALS(D2="False"; B2&" 
"&"Disabled op: "&TEKST(E2;"d-m-jjjj uu:mm"); B2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to enter a formula you should

- Use the `Formula` property instead of the `Value` property
- Write the formula using EN-US locale (for function names, etc) - or use the `FormulaLocal` property if you like, but then someone in another locale will get an error if they try to use your code
- ensure that any `"` marks inside the formula are escaped by using `""` instead

```
Sub AddData() 
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(D2=""False"", B2&"" Disabled op: ""&TEXT(E2,""d-m-jjjj uu:mm""), B2)" 
End Sub
```

I **think** I translated your formula correctly.  See if it works (i.e. after entering in the cell it looks like what you wanted) and, if not, I'll have another look.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created two functions call ALS() and TEKST() then just change .Value to .Formula and you need double "" for quotation within the formula

Comment: `ALS` and `TEKST` will **probably** be `IF` and `TEXT` when translated to the OP's Excel locale.